# Xamarin Android custom view from library

Tags: android, xamarin

I created Android Xamarin project and library. In library I have custom view

```
public class TextInputField : LinearLayout
{
    public TextInputField(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public TextInputField(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public TextInputField(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
        : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    { 
        View.Inflate(this.Context, Resource.Layout.textinputfield, this);
    }
}
```

The resource is referenced to `axml` defined in library and it is `LinearLayout`. The resource build action is `AndroidResource`.

When I run the application, it crashes with `ResourcesNotFoundException`. It somehow refers `Resource.Layout.textinputfield` to applications resources not libraries.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Right click on layout file in library -> Properties -> Include in deploy